# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pylearn2.space

Tags: git, theano, pylearn, pylearn2

```
 ! git clone git://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2.git'''
 ! pip install theano
```

I am working on `Google colab`. I have installed the `pylearn2` clone from `git` but still it is showing `MODULE NOT FOUND` error in the following lines

```
 pylearn2.space import VectorSpace
 from pylearn2.costs.cost import Cost
```

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylearn2.space
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylearn2.costs.cost
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see: https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2

No PyPI packages. The repo was last updated 5 years ago. There is a big warning:

> This project does not have any current developer. We will continue to review pull requests and merge them when appropriate, but do not expect new development unless someone decides to work on it.

Doesn't look right.

Installation instructions at http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/#download-and-installation say you need to install it after cloning:

```
python setup.py develop
```